Votes cast statistic is unclear
Here is the votes cast statistic on my StackOverflow profile:

It says I have voted 4 times this month but 8 times this week. How is that even possible? Does the statistic account for all votes including this week or not including this week? Otherwise this is definitely a bug.
This problem also exists on other SE sites


It says I have voted 4 times this month but [8] times this week. How is that even possible

The week starts on 2024-09-29, while the month starts on 2024-10-01.
